# How to disable scientific notation in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to enter `7029000044E3` but it is showing `7029000044000`.

I cleared formating cells and tried format cells custom in 0.

Comment: You could just do `='7029000044E3` (note the apostrophe after the `=`). Do you plan on using the numbers?

Comment: Thanq @BruceWayne , I used `'` , its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I use the technic to format cell text.
Select column->Format Cells-> Custom->Type then 0 -> OK.

Hopefully it will remove scientific notation.